# How to know the commented page url for facebook comments moderation?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

We have integrated facebook comments plugin for our website with about 8 lakh dynamically created pages(all similar purpose). The `href` for the comments plugin is dynamically generated, same as the page url.

Further we have created an app for the same and obtained an appId for moderation of comments by adding the required meta tag.

On the dashboard of the account we see the user comments as they are posted with the public comments and moderator views, but we are unable to obtain the actual url of the page on which the comment has been made.

This may be required sometimes to reply to some question that a user has asked on the page.

The reply can be made from the dashboard but certain information in the user query is hidden in the context of the page, so unless we know the actual page url, we are unable to solve the query.

Please let me know how can I know the url of the page on which the comment was made.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'd need the same info just now.

Comment: And almost at the same time I found the solution myself! :) I might as well write it here as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to go to the comments moderation tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?id=YourAppId).

There you'll see by default the 'Public Comments' view. From the same row where the Settings link is change the view to 'Moderator view'.

There are all the comments listed (just like in the public comments if there's any) but under the comment there is a 'Visit Website' link and that link throws you straight to the correct page.